# In Java/Scala how to get specific UTC date in seconds with minimal amount of code/ in most elegant way?

Tags: java, scala, utc, epoch, aerospike

To be more specific I need:

```
// seconds from Jan 1 2010
val currentAerospikeTime = (new Date().getTime - new Date(110, 0, 1).getTime)/1000;
```

But it uses the deprecated `Date` constructor, so I get a warning. But in Scala there is no way to turn off the warning for a single line (and I don't want to turn it off completely). So how can I rewrite it, to make it terser and let it compile without the warning?

Maybe I'm missing something but I can't find a short way to do it, neither with the Java 8 API nor with the Joda library (didn't reserch it thoroughly, but I don't want to add the library just for this line either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`ChronoUnit#between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) to work this out, e.g.:

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(
    LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 1).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Z")), 
    ZonedDateTime.now());
```

Or alternatively, really terse:

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1262304000000L) / 1000;
```

Comment: Second one is clearly the winner. Shame for me that I didn't came to this myself. Got too lazy using .Net :-)

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 and JodaTime there is a concept of Duration.

The number of seconds since 1-1-2010 can be determined by (java 8 example)

```
LocalDateTime jan2010 = LocalDate.of(2010,1,1).atStartOfDay(); // can also pass a ZoneId here
Long secondsSince2010 = Duration.of(jan2010, LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds();
```

For JodaTime the solution is similar, only the construction of objects and methods are slightly different.

Comment: That's actual even better than mine because it doesn't use that `parse` method with the encoded timezone `'Z'` and is a bit more explicit with `atStartOfDay`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the new time API (which is based on Joda Time) for this:

```
long diffInSeconds = Duration.between(Instant.parse("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"), Instant.now()).getSeconds();
```

What I dislike about the `Calendar` solution:

- where to get the `Calendar` instance to get from? You have to make sure, that the time (hour, minutes, ...) which is included in it is the one you want to as well.
- It's the old API, the newer ones are always more shiny ;)

Joke aside, the newer API is really more precise.
I wouldn't use that `getSeconds()` method there and stick with the `Duration` object instead. I have just included it to demonstrate that you can get the exact same thing (but imho `Duration` is a clearer type for a ... duration ... than `long`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the constructor in the class Date, what about trying Calendar?

```
Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date);
```

It's what is recommended in the javadoc of the deprecated constructor you looked for.

Comment: I tried to write the expression with Calendar before posting the question but it's several lines of code intead of one actually. Not so terse. But thanks for input anyways.